# Android Chrome disable auto-suggest on search input form

Tags: android, google-chrome, input

I have the following search form:

```
<div id="search_banner">
    <form id="intranet_search" class="search" action="<?=base_url()?>search/">
        <div id="intranet_search_search_bar">
            <input type="search" id="intranet_search_q" name="q" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="false" autocorrect="false" placeholder="search intranet" value="<?=$intranet_search_query?>" />
            <input type="search" id="intranet_search_ac_hint" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="false" autocorrect="false" disabled />
            <input type="submit" id="intranet_search_button" value="Search">
        </div>
        <div id="intranet_search_ac"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Which emulates Google's autosuggest inserted into the element `#intranet_search_ac` via javascript. This works as expected.

However on Chrome for Android (40.0.02214.109) I get the following suggestion appearing on top of my suggestions (highlighted below):

[image: Chrome auto-complete]

As you can see from the form I am using the usual `spellcheck="false" autocomplete="false" autocorrect="false"` attributes.  Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using 
`autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false"`

Comment: You learn something new everyday... off != false in this case

Comment: Yeah unfortunately a falsy/truthy value doesn't work, it's very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible. I reported a ticket to support autosuggest="off", you can vote for it. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=901839